# Elementary calculus confusion why is $\varphi(t)-\pi_k\varphi(t) = \int_{\tilde{t}}^{t}\dot{\varphi}(s) \ ds$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, projection

> **Problem:** Let $\pi_k\varphi(t)$ be the $L_2-$projection of $\varphi$ into piecewise constants, i.e
>
> $$\int_{I_j}\pi_k\varphi(t)=\int_{I_j}\varphi(t).\tag 1$$
>
> Show that for a subinterval $I_j=(t_{j-1}, t_j)$, with $t_j=jk$ and
>    $k$ being a positive constant
>
> $$\int_{I_j}|\varphi(s)-\pi_k\varphi(s)| \ ds\leq
>  k\int_{I_j}|\dot{\varphi}(s)| \ ds, \quad
>  \dot{\varphi}(t)=\frac{d\varphi}{dt}. \tag2$$

---

**Question 1:**

**1)**  Why does $(1)$ hold? How do I intuitively see it?

---

**Question 2 & 3:** In the solution suggestion they write

[image]

**2)** Why is that first assumption crucial? Can't we project $\varphi$ without it crossing path with $\pi_k\varphi$?

**3)** I don't see how that last equation follows. The LHS just gives us the vertical distance between the red and blue line. If we evaluate the integral we get

$$\varphi(t)-\pi_k\varphi(t)=\varphi(t)-\varphi(\tilde{t}) \ \Longleftrightarrow \pi_k\varphi(t)=\varphi(\tilde{t}), \tag 3$$

Which is clearly not true. What am I missing?

Comment: Is $k$ in $t_j=jk$ the same as in the integral? I think I can make sense of the formulas if $k$ wasn't in this expression.

Comment: In which integral? Do you mean in (2)? Or do you mean as subindex in the $\pi_k$ in(1)? But in either way it's the same $k$.

Comment: Better clarify the three appearances of $k$. If it is the same, as it seems to be, maybe we need to know its meaning.

Comment: Ok this is the deal: $\pi_k\varphi(t)$ can just be written as another function $g(t)$.

Comment: I think that $k$ is very relevant for anyone to understand the interest the result the problem gives. It is the length of each one of the intervals $I_j$ as the answer given by Misk clarifies. The point is how the  integral mean value theorem is used here.

Comment: That's correct, they are using a partition of uniform interval length $|I_j| = k$. Have you been able to make any sense of the intrgral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F:= \{ \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_n \chi_{I_n}: c_n \in \mathbb R, I_n = [(n-1)k,nk), \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_n^2<\infty\}$ denote the inner product space of the piecewise constant functions you mentioned. In $L^2(\mathbb R)$ the inner product is defined by $\langle f ,g \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)g(x)dx .$ It is easy to show that the set $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt k} \chi_{I_n} , n\in\mathbb Z \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal F$, since $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\chi_{I_n}(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt k} \chi_{I_m}(x)dx = \delta_{nm}. $ Okay so the othogonal projection of $\varphi\in L^2$ is given by
$$  P_{\mathcal F} \varphi(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \langle \varphi,v_n\rangle v_n(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \frac{1}{k}\int_{I_n} \varphi(t)dt\cdot  \chi_{I_n}(x)= \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \pi_k\varphi(x), $$
where $v_n(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt k} \chi_{I_n}(x)$. Now fix $x\in I_n$ for some $n$. Due the integral mean value theorem
$$ \frac1k\int_{I_n} \varphi(x)dx = \varphi(\xi)   $$
for some $\xi\in I_n$. We also know that
$$ \frac1k \int_{I_n} \varphi(x)dx = \pi_k\varphi(t) \quad \mbox{ for any } t \in I_n $$ hence for $\eta>\xi$
$$ \varphi(\eta)-\pi_k\varphi(\eta) =\varphi(\eta)-\varphi(\xi)= \int_{\xi}^\eta \varphi'(t)dt \leq \int_{\xi}^\eta |\varphi'(t)|dt $$
from which follows
$$ |\varphi(\eta)-\pi_k\varphi|\le \int_{\xi}^\eta|\varphi'(t)|dt .$$
If $\eta<\xi$ then
$$ \pi_k\varphi- \varphi(\eta) =\int_{\eta}^\xi\varphi'(t)dt   $$
from which we get similarly
$$ |\varphi(\eta)-\pi_k\varphi| \leq \int_{\eta}^\xi |\varphi'(t)|dt $$
Now we have 
$$ |\varphi(\eta)-\pi_k\varphi|\leq \int_{\min(\xi,\eta)}^{\max(\xi,\eta)}|\varphi'(t)|dt \le \int_{I_n} |\varphi'(t)|dt \quad \mbox{ for any } \eta \in I_n $$
 Now integrating this w.r.t. to $\eta$ yields
$$ \int_{I_n} |\varphi(\eta)-\pi_k\varphi|d\eta\leq k\int_{I_n}|\varphi'(t)|dt $$

Comment: I thank you for the answer, however I think this is above my level and you did not really answer any of my 3 questions. I have so many questions about your post that I dont even know where to begin.

Comment: 1) that's quasi the definition of the projection. Are you familiar with conditional probability or projection in an abstract Hilbert space? The projection is constant on the intervals $I_n$ and the integral of the projection equals the integral of the original function. 2) this is due to the integral mean value theorem, plus the properties of the projection. 3) see my calculations. I just used different symbols than $t$ and $\tilde t$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I tried to provide a full solution to the exercise and thought it'd clear things up.